# NewtonSoft.Json error of version?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have installed newtonSoft.json version 6.0.0.0 but I am getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I do not want to keep NewtonSoft version 6.0.0.0 and do not want to upgrade that. Please suggest me how to resolve the problem.

Comment: What assemblies have you referenced? Do they depend on NS.Json version 8?

Comment: No there is no assembly that depend on that..

Comment: Take a look at your app/web.config there may be an assembly redirect pointing at version 8.0.0.0

Comment: No there is not such thing. I already have checked that

Comment: We've had some really strange dependency issues with Newtonsoft.Json lately.  Even if you don't have an assembly redirect pointing at the *wrong* version, I'd suggest adding one that points at the *right* version.

Comment: Hi
The problem was that my library project and my Api project were not using the same version of NewtonSoft.Json and ow I made them same i.e 6.0.0.0 and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You use another library that reference to a newer version of Newtonsoft.

Why you don't want to upgrade to version `8.0.0`?

Comment: Because I already have installed libraries that uses the NewtonSoft.Json lower version so I not want to change that....

Comment: You can use newer version with libraries that need older version. You need assembly redirect. It's automatic when you install newtonsoft from nuget.

Comment: Hi The problem was that my library project and my Api project were not using the same version of NewtonSoft.Json and now I made them same i.e 6.0.0.0 and its working fine